Construct spatial network of natural tunnels via 3D raytracing in R
Short question: How to do 3D ray-tacing/collision-detection, in R?
Longer question:
I have a 3-dimensional triangular mesh of animal burrows in soil produced my a micro-CT scanner (wavefront file format). The mesh consists of thousands of triangles, each defined by three xyz coordinates for the corners, and I have calculated the centre of each triangle.
My overall goal is to characterize 'use areas' within burrows and their spatial relationships. Perhaps first I need to further 'down sample' my CT triangles and develop an index of points to triangulate orthogonal to the burrow paths, then connect centers of those with lines instead of ray tracing. The file has no material (though mirrors might be good, if such exists).
If ray tracing: I would like to represent the spatial relationships between the different locations in the burrow as a spatial network; vertices would represent triangles, and an edge would be drawn whenever there is a direct line-of-sight between two triangles, that is, whenever the line connecting the two triangle centres does not intersect any part of the mesh.
Obviously (or perhaps not obviously), to prevent impossible edges, one needs to ensure that the lines of sight are constrained to travel within the empty cavities of the burrow, never across the filled spaces.
So, how does one test for line-polygon intersections in 3D space in R..?
If orthogonal to existing triangles: How to specify points to triangulate across the void (burrow) rather than along.
Here is data for my attempt example below: First, you'll need to download micro-CT wavefront.obj data, here: https://filebin.net/lkjrr193wyjjup8s
library(rgl)

## str(mesh) should produce a list of 6, with mesth$vb and mesh$it as the 1st & 2nd entries...
mesh <- rgl::readOBJ ("resampled_20_wavefront.obj")

triangle_index_df <- t(mesh$it)       ## lists all the triangles in the surface
coordinates_df    <- t(mesh$vb)[,1:3] ## coordinates of all the vertices of the triangle

##  access coordinates of the vertices of the ith triangle:
N_Triangles      <- nrow(triangle_index_df)
Triangle_centres <- matrix(NA, nrow=N_Triangles, ncol=3); colnames(Triangle_centres) <- c("x","y","z") 

## Calculate the centre of each triangle
WhichTriangles <- 1:N_Triangles
for (i in 1:N_Triangles)
 { if (i%%1000==0){print(paste(i, "of", N_Triangles))}
 tricoords <- coordinates_df [triangle_index_df[i,],  ]
 ## coordinates of centre of that triangle:
 Cent <- colMeans(coordinates_df[triangle_index_df[i,],],na.rm=T)
 Triangle_centres[i,] <- Cent
 # triangles3d(tricoords,col="red3", alpha=0.4)
 }
shade3d(mesh , col="green4", alpha=0.3)
points3d(Triangle_centres, col='red3')

It looks like my burrow has the measles. spdep::dnearneigh seems to have 3d capability for distance.
This is as far as I've gotten. Any thoughts greatly appreciated.

I do not understand why this question was closed - it does not ' .. seek ... recommendations for software libraries, tutorials, tools, books, or other off-site resources.'  Whilst I see that the reproducible example is not completely reproducible, the nature of the question - ray-tracing in complex environments - requires a complex dataset to demonstrate the approach - I can't exactly paste the dataset as a 1-liner in the code.. (well,I could, but you wouldn't thank me...!)

Thank you. I think the confusion may be because I loaded the readobj library, but then didn't use the read.object function from that library - I instead reverted the the slower but simpler readOBJ from rgl. I have edited the code to specify rgl::readOBJ.  Does that work?

Sorry for the time-suck! I am on Linux mint, R  3.6.3 (sorry!), and rgl_0.100.54 ...

Yes, it would be great if you could please try to re-open the question - thank you.                   There is one initial entrance - in the centre of the x,y plane & at the top of the z-axis.

I don't think you get to your desired spatial network using a wavefront .obj file as much 'spatial' data is lost in converting from whatever might have been initial data format to .obj, 'where' is reduced to 'what' to produce a picture, albeit 3d, and as 'z' is positive the burrow is above ground.
